# Is this a bug or documentation error in R's `poly` function?

Tags: r, matrix

From the details section of `?poly`:

> Although formally degree should be named (as it follows ...), an
>   unnamed second argument of length 1 will be interpreted as the degree,
>   such that poly(x, 3) can be used in formulas.

Giving

```
poly( as.matrix(1:5) , 2 , raw = TRUE )
```

interprets the second argument as a constant and returns

```
     1.0 2.0 0.1 1.1 0.2
[1,]   1   1   2   2   4
[2,]   2   4   2   4   4
[3,]   3   9   2   6   4
[4,]   4  16   2   8   4
[5,]   5  25   2  10   4
```

Furthermore `poly( as.matrix(1:5) , 2 , raw = FALSE)` returns an error.

Is this rather a bug or a documentation error and should it be [reported](https://www.r-project.org/bugs.html)?

Comment: Hint: The output will be different (and probably what you expected) if you use `poly(as.matrix(1:5), degree = 2, raw = TRUE)` (and in that case you *can* also use raw = FALSE).

Comment: @Dason I see, so it interpreted the second number not as `degree` but as a constant. That's surprising. The `1.1` column seems to be some sort of interactions term. I wonder if it's possible to omit that one?

Comment: @Dason Also the details section of `?poly` is then very ambiguous, as it says there: "Although formally degree should be named (as it follows ...), an unnamed second argument of length 1 will be interpreted as the degree, such that `poly(x, 3)` can be used in formulas."

Comment: There does seem to be either a bug or the documentation isn't quite right

Comment: @Dason I will amend this question in this direction.